# PDO : Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: mysql, pdo, parameters

I can't figure out why I am getting the **SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens** error message with the following code:

```
$myArr = array(283908,283951,284024,284064,284076,284099);
$num = count($myArr);

$req = "select * from MyTable where Id in (?,?,?,?,?,?) limit ?,?";

$start = 0;
$limit = 3;

try {
   $sql = $pdo->prepare($req);
   $sql->bindParam($num+1, $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
   $sql->bindParam($num+2, $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
   $sql->execute($myArr);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
   pdo_error($e->getMessage());
}
```

The first 6 questions marks are bound with myArr content and the 2 last ones with limits. This is just an example, in the real life myArr can content more than 100 values and its size is not fixed.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `PDOStatement::execute()` with an array of parameters, it will not use the parameters specified in calls to `PDOStatement::bindParam()`. Instead, just append the `$start` and `$limit` variable to the end of `$myArr` and call `$sql->execute()`.

```
try {
   $sql = $pdo->prepare($req);
   $myArr[] = $start
   $myArr[] = $limit

   $sql->execute($myArr);
}
```

See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php#97531) comment on the PHP PDO documentation.

Comment: No, it doesn't work as expected: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''0','3'' at line 1

Comment: $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false ); solved that, thank you